# file_put_contents() memory leak in PHP

Tags: php, linux, memory-leaks, cpanel

I have implemented a simple caching mechanism in PHP which saves the content of the output buffer in an HTML file and in the next request if the file exists, it will return the file content instead of fetching data from the database or whatever.

The code is like this, so simple:

```
$content = ob_get_contents();
if (!is_dir($cacheFolderPath))
    mkdir($cacheFolderPath);
      
file_put_contents($filePath, $content);
```

The mechanism is working as expected both on development and production. However, when I use it on production which is a shared Cpanel host, the usage of the memory increase significantly, and when I delete the file from the server hard disk the memory usage gets back to normal. But again as visitors visit the pages and the cache files create, the usage goes up again. You can see the chart below which shows the memory usage today. Anywhere that I have drawn the red star, it is when I deleted all the created files by the code above.

[image]

It seems that when `file_put_contents()` create a file on the hard, it also creates a reference of it on the memory without any reason. And when I delete the file, since the original file does not exist, the reference on the memory released automatically.

I have search a lot and have not found any memory leak problem with `file_get_contents()` but it seems that there are some issues.

What I have tested:

- Changing PHP versions => No change
- Using `fopen, fwrite, fclose` instead => No change
- Testing on Windows development enviorenment => No memory leak issue
- Commenting out the code above on production => Memory leak issue disapears as well

Any comments, same experiences with any possible solutions, hints, etc. is hightly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like your temp dir is on tmpfs, i.e. a RAM disk. Try writing it to somewhere backed by a disk instead of RAM.

Comment: I am saving the files in a folder at the root of the project. I don't think that it is related. However, that was something that I did not think about. Thanks.

Comment: You can easily check with `df -T` or reading `/proc/mounts`. You should also make sure that this graph does not count VFS cache, since a healthy Linux system will basically always have ~99% physical memory usage technically speaking ([LinuxAteMyRam](https://www.linuxatemyram.com))